# Limit one-to-many with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I have classes:

```cs
public class Game
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Game")]
    public virtual ICollection<GameMember> Members { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class GameMember
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid GameID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Members")]
    [ForeignKey("GameID")]
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make a simple online game. Users can join the game (in that case a new `GameMember` will be created) and get to the lobby. When everybody is ready, the game starts. I am wondering if there is simple way to limit the number of members. It would be great if I can just apply some attribute like `[Max(4)]` to `ICollection<GameMember> Members`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible - there is no equivalent construct in SQL.
You will need to create four properties, one per allowed member.